# Input value of a textbox to prepend an unorganised list (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, textbox, html-lists, message, prepend

I'm looking to prepend what a user enters into the "typetextbox" onto the "messagebox" UL.

**HTML code:**

```
<ul id="messagebox">
<li></li>
</ul>

<div>
<input type="text" id="typetextbox" maxlength="120" autocomplete="off" />

<button id="submit"> </button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){
    var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
    $('#messagebox').prepend("<br/>");
});
});
```

If I were to type something into the Prepend brackets, that's what shows up, but this code right now doesnt show any of the text that I write into the textbox when I hit submit. Why? How do I get the value of the textbox added to the prepend list?

Im sure its a simple problem I'm overlooking but any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#submit').click(function(){
      var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
      $('#messagebox').prepend(message + "<br/>");
   });
});
```

or do you mean:

```
$('#messagebox').prepend("<li>" + message + "</li>");
```

If you want HTML special characters entered by the user to be encoded (so that `<b>bold</b>` entered into the text box stays `<b>bold</b>` and does not give **bold** text), try

```
$('#messagebox').prepend($("<li />").text (message));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not prepending any value of the textarea instead you are only prepending a line break. Take a look at your code one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much JohnB!!!

I originally had the < message + 
 > in, but found every time I hit submit, "message +" was prepended to the list. Something as simple as adding quotations over the line break has made it work. Thank you very much!

Quick question though, my button only works when I click it. How do I get it to submit when I press Enter?

Thanks again!